# Conditional Addition of elements in to a list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a multi-dimensional array of `double dSet[,]` where each row has 1500 elements. I have a `List<int> index`, with say 100 integers of values (0 - 1499) . Now, I have to create a `List<double> val` with 100 elements,  where each element is dSet[0,i], where i is an element of `List<int> index`. I know that it can be done easily using a simple loop. I was wondering whether it can be done using a single statement using LinQ in C#.

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers. Sorry but I forgot to mention that dSet is passed as ref :(. Can it be done now ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
index.Select(i => dSet[0, i]).ToList();
```

The key is to select into your `index` list, selecting a single value from `dSet` for each value in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Sure - that's just a projection from each element of the index:

```
List<double> val = index.Select(i => dSet[0, i]).ToList();
```

Any time you've got something along the lines of "for each element from *source*, do something to get an output value based on that element", that's likely to end up as `source.Select(...)` where the `...` is an expression of the "do something to get an output value based on that element".

The `ToList()` just converts the result (an `IEnumerable<double>`) into a `List<double>`.